# Excel 2010 charts from ungrouped data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a sheet that contains lots of information about jobs in a company. One of the columns is "city". That column contains values as such

```
Falun
Borlänge
Stockholm
Uppsala
Borlänge
Stockholm
Stockholm
```

Now i'd like to use this data and visualize it using a chart. However, the data is "ungrouped". What i'd actually like the charts to present, is the number of occurencies of each city. How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a "PivotChart" - and simply draw the "City" field both - to the x-Axis and to the data field. The Pivot table will automatically count the number of occurrences.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you. I tried using the "regular" chart tools...
Is it possible to tell the pivotchart to use the same data filters as i apply to the source data?

Comment: Almost. You cannot link the filter - however, you can apply the same filter settings by dragging the fields to be filtered to the filter section of the pivot and then filter accordingly!